# How to use cmake with freopen in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a small console program and I want to direct stdin/stdout to a read/write from txt files located in the same directory with the cpp file. 
the cpp look something like this:

```
int main(){
   freopen("in.txt","r",stdin);
   freopen("out.txt","w",stdout);
   //read input
   scanf(...);
   //proccess input
   //proccsing....
   //output
   printf(...);
}
```

and the CMakeLists.txt file look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(ACM)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(ACM ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

The project builds successfully, but it doesn't produce any output. After checking I noticed that freopen is failing to find the txt files.
what should I add to CMakeLists.txt to include txt files in the build ?
PS: I'm a noob in CMake so a detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: _"After checking I noticed that freopen is failing to find the txt files"_ How is that related to the build process? I removed all of the irrelevant tags. The files you want to access need to be in the same directory your program is started from, that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need it for debug purpose, add the following definition to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_definitions(-DSRC_PATH="${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

and reopen files like this:

```
freopen(SRC_PATH"/in.txt","r",stdin);
freopen(SRC_PATH"/out.txt","w",stdout);
```

It works on Linux, should work on other unix-like platforms and may require some additional manipulation with slashes under Windows. Anyway, you may debug it through `printf("%s\n", SRC_PATH"/in.txt");`.

Answer (score 0):

> After checking I noticed that freopen is failing to find the txt files. what should I add to CMakeLists.txt to include txt files in the build ?

As mentioned (and why I removed the irrelevant [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake) tag), that has nothing to do with the build process that creates your executable program.

There's nothing to add into your `CMakeLists.txt` file.

If you want to have access to these files when running your program, either ensure that your program runs in the same working directory, as where these text files exist, or use fully qualified file paths to open them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not specify a path in the file names you are opening, they must be in the current directory at the time your program is run. I fleshed out your program just a bit so that it would actually build:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   freopen("in.txt","r",stdin);
   freopen("out.txt","w",stdout);

   //read input
   int i;
   scanf("%d", &i);

   //output
   printf("Read: %d\n", i);
}
```

After I ran this with `in.txt` containing one line consisting of `5`, the file out.txt contained `Read: 5`, as expected. I used Linux and gcc, and did everything on the command line, with everything in the same directory. If you want them to be in any directory other than the current directory, you will need to add paths

Even after you get it working, it would be good to add plenty of error checking, including checking the return value from `freopen` to be sure it succeeds, and to the return value of scanf to make sure it succeeds. Or better yet, avoid scanf, especially if you are reading strings, since it is unsafe.